# Nodejs REST API with Websocket

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, redis, socket.io

I have to applications: The front end and the backend.

The front end is simply a map that displays realtime data, like points on a map and events etc. This will use react and leaflet.

The back end is simply a rest api that receives posts with geo data. Once the data is received and saved, a websocket needs to push this data to the front end map.

For the backend bit I will be using Node.js with Express and Socket.IO.

I am a bit confused about what to use for the DB.

Redis would probably work best for websocket connections, but mongo better for saving geojson data, photos etc?

Or I should probably not even use a DB for the websockets? Isnt it simply  a push to the websocket after a save in the db for certain resources, like geo locations etc?

Answer (score 1):

The websocket connections will be initiated by your browser front end and accepted by your node.js server. You'll need a way for your front end to figure out what `wss://geo.example.com/endpoint` url to hit, and how to authenticate those connections.

A dbms (redis or whatever) will persist your incoming geo data. But you should also push it out over the open websocket or websockets to your front ends that need it.

When each browser first connects its websocket connection, you may want to immediately push some backlog of geo data as well.